# What do I need to close when using PrintWriter in Java

Tags: java, try-catch, filewriter, printwriter, bufferedwriter

When using a `PrintWriter` like this :

```
PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFileIn)));
```

What do I need to close in the finally block ? The PrintWriter, the BufferedWriter and the FileWriter ?

Do I need to try catch the close statement in the finally block ?

[EDIT]
I need to use java 6, so I can't use the try-with-resources statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use -

```
fileOut.close();
```

As you do not have any variable name assigned to `BufferedWriter` or `FileWriter` also the `fileOut` is made from them when you close `fileOut` it will in turn close both the streams.

Comment: Do I need a try catch arround this close ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a *try-with-resources* block

```
try (PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new     FileWriter(csvFileIn)))) {
    //WHATEVER you need to do
}
```

Since `PrintWriter` implements `AutoCloseable` it will close by itself once the *try* block is complete (even if an exception is raised)

Check more info about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you should close all three streams. And I would even add a fourth layer, since you probably don’t want to write out the CSV file using the *default system encoding*, but a customer-specified one. So this is it:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(csvFileIn);
     FileWriter fwr = new FileWriter(fos, StandardEncodings.UTF_8);
     BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(fwr);
     PrintWriter pwr = new PrintWriter(bwr)) {
  pwr.println("Field1;Field2;Field3");
  pwr.println("Data1;Data2;Data3");
}
```

In practice, usually only the outermost stream is closed, since it (usually) forwards the `close()` call to its wrapped stream, and getting an `OutOfMemoryError` between opening the file and reaching the `try` block is very unlikely. Then, it looks like this:

```
try (PrintWriter pwr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new FileOutputStream(csvFileIn), StandardEncodings.UTF_8)))) {
  pwr.println("Field1;Field2;Field3");
  pwr.println("Data1;Data2;Data3");
}
```